# Redireccionamiento temporal 302 a nuevo dominio con .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirección, dominio

Hola estoy realizando un redireccionamiento temporal 302 usando .htaccess mi codigo es

```
# BEGIN test redirect
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.dominio_nuevo.com  [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
# END test redirect
```

Si ingreso en la carpeta de mi localhost donde esta el .htacess redirecciona al nuevo dominio, con la siguiente url

```
http://localhost/pruebas/redirect_htacces
```

Pero para redireccionar a otra página del mismo sitio por ejemplo http://www.dominio_nuevo.com/contactenos.html  el htacces no redirecciona, lo escribo en la url de la siguiente forma

```
http://localhost/pruebas/redirect_htacces/contactenos.html
```

Comment: Por cierto, te sobra un `RewriteEngine on` (el segundo, que ya no hace falta si lo pusiste antes)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto debería valerte.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

> Entiendo que el problema es que te falta redireccionar después del
>   nuevo dominio, el contenido que RewriteRule ha detectado que llega en
>   la URL (el parámetro $1)

Por último, se me olvidaba, recuerda recargar la configuración para el servicio httpd

```
 /sbin/service httpd reload
```